# Add User Functionality at custom admin side - Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I am working on a project in Python Djnago 3.1.2, and developing a custom admin side, where admin can perform different functionalities.

At the admin site I want to add functionality to add user and I have created a function but there is some error but I could not get it.

Here is My models.
**models.py**

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    GENDER = (
        (True, 'Male'),
        (False, 'Female'),
    )
    USER_TYPE = (
        ('Admin', 'Admin'),
        ('Designer', 'Designer'),
        ('Customer', 'Customer'),
    )
    user_id = models.AutoField("User ID", primary_key=True, auto_created=True)
    avatar = models.ImageField("User Avatar", null=True, blank=True)
    gender = models.BooleanField("Gender", choices=GENDER, default=True)
    role = models.CharField("User Type", max_length=10, choices=USER_TYPE, default='Customer')

    def __str__(self):
        return "{}".format(self.user_id)
```

This is the function I have created and I think error is in my views.
**views.py**

```
def addUser(request):
    form = CreateUserForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CreateUserForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()

            return redirect('/admin1/addUser')
    else:
        addUser_show = User.objects.all()
        # start paginator logic
        paginator = Paginator(addUser_show, 3)
        page = request.GET.get('page')
        try:
            addUser_show = paginator.page(page)
        except PageNotAnInteger:
            addUser_show = paginator.page(1)
        except EmptyPage:
            addUser_show = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
        # end paginator logic
        return render(request, 'admin1/addUser.html',
                      {'addUser_show': addUser_show, "form":form})
```

**urls.py**

```
path('addUser/', views.addUser, name="admin-add-user"),
```

Form I am using to get the create user form.
**forms.py**

```
class CreateUserForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User

        fields = ['username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'avatar', 'email', 'password1', 'password2', 'gender', 'role']
```

**addUser.html**

```
{% extends 'admin1/layout/master.html' %}
{% block title %}Add User{% endblock %}
{% block main %}
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-2"></div>
        <div class="col-lg-10">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mt-2" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-primary">Add
                User
            </button>
            <div class="modal fade" id="modal-primary">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h4 class="modal-title">Add User</h4>
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body mt-2">
                            <form action="{% url 'admin-add-user'%}" method="POST"
                                  enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                {% csrf_token %}
                                <table border="1" class="table table-bordered border border-info">
                                    {{form.as_p}}
                                    <div class="modal-footer justify-content-right">
                                        <input type="Submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"
                                               class="btn btn-outline-success">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                </table>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.modal-content -->
                </div>
                <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
            </div>

            <!-- /.modal -->

            <br>
            <div class="container-fluid ">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="card mt-2 border border-secondary">
                        <div class="card-header">
                            <h3 class="card-title ">Product Table</h3>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.card-header -->
                        <div class="card-body">

                            <table class="table table-bordered border border-info">
                                <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>User Id</th>
                                    <th>User Name</th>
                                    <th>User First Name</th>
                                    <th>User Last Name</th>
                                    <th>User Email</th>
                                    <th>User Gender</th>
                                    <th>User Avatar</th>
                                    <th>Role</th>
                                    <th>Action</th>
                                </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody class="justify-content-center">
                                {% for x in addUser_show %}

                                <tr>
                                    <td>{{x.user_id}}</td>
                                    <td>{{x.username}}</td>
                                    <td>{{x.first_name}}</td>
                                    <td>{{x.last_name}}</td>
                                    <td>{{x.email}}</td>
                                    <td>{{x.gender}}</td>
                                    <td><img src="{{x.avatar.url}}" alt="{{x.avatar}}" height="100" width="100">
                                    </td>
                                    <td>{{x.role}}</td>
                                    <td><a href="#"
                                           class="btn btn-outline-primary mt-2"><i
                                            class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                                        <a href="#"
                                           class="btn btn-outline-danger mt-2"><i
                                                class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                                        <a href="#"
                                           class="btn btn-outline-warning mt-2"><i
                                                class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>

                                {% endfor %}

                                </tbody>
                            </table>

                        </div>
                        <!-- /.card-body -->
                        <div class="card-footer clearfix ">
                            <ul class="pagination pagination-sm m-0 justify-content-center">
                                {% if addUser_show.has_previous %}
                                <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link"
                                                         href="?page={{product_show.previous_page_number}}">
                                    Previous </a>
                                </li>
                                {% endif%}
                                {% for x in addUser_show.paginator.page_range %}

                                {% if addUser_show.number == x %}
                                <li class="page-item active"><a class="page-link" href="?page={{x}}">{{x}}</a></li>
                                {% else%}
                                <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?page={{x}}">{{x}}</a></li>
                                {% endif %}
                                {% endfor %}

                                {% if addUser_show.has_next %}
                                <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link"
                                                         href="?page={{addUser_show.next_page_number}}"> Next </a>
                                </li>
                                {% endif %}
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.card -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Here I want to make admin able to create new user. but I am getting error shown below while submission of
form. My form works proper till it display the form , but when I fill up details and submit the form it shows the following error.

[image: it is error image]

[image: error]

If possible please write the answer.

Comment: When the request method is "POST" and the form is not valid you are returning None. You should return the same response as a GET but with the validated form in the context

Comment: you do not return HttpResponse if form is not valid

Comment: **        else:
            return render(request, 'admin1/addUser.html',
                          { "form": form})**   I heve added this if form is not valid ,then this should be done, it is now not showing error but the user is not added to the model.

Comment: That means that your form has errors and they are normally listed above form fields https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/#form-rendering-options and your form is in modal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried something and its working for me but I don't know that it is right way to do it or not.

**view.py**

```
def addUser(request):
    form = CreateUserForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CreateUserForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()

            return redirect('/admin1/addUser')

    addUser_show = User.objects.all()
    # start paginator logic
    paginator = Paginator(addUser_show, 3)
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        addUser_show = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        addUser_show = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        addUser_show = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
    # end paginator logic
    return render(request, 'admin1/addUser.html',
                  {'addUser_show': addUser_show,"form":form})
```